# Spring mvc - <form:checkboxes are checked only for first element from the list

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, jsp

**Hello**,

I have provided list of objects to JSP view file. Each of the object has own *form:form* with *form:checkboxes*.

My object has field:

```
    private List<Object_2> object_2List;
```

**object_2List** has only five stable elements in database.Checkboxes print all elements and check those, which object has defined to field given above.

The problem is, checkboxes are checked only for first element from provided list.

It is hard to explain with words, so let me give you some code and pictures.

**This is my controller:**

provided here are lists of objects_1 and object_2 to JSP view.

```
@ModelAttribute("objects_1")
public List<Object_1> objects_1List() {
    return object_1Service.getAllObjects_1();
}

@ModelAttribute("objects_2")
public List<Object_2> objects_2List() {
    return object_2Service.getAllObjects_2();
}

@GetMapping("/admin")
public String adminLandingPage(Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("object_1", new Object_1());
    return "admin/admin-home";
}

@PostMapping("/admin")
public String updateObject_1(Object_1 object_1) {
    object_1Service.updateObject_1(object_1);
    return "admin/admin-home";
}
```

}

**This is my view jsp file:**

```
    <c:forEach items="${objects_1}" var="object_1Loop" varStatus="x">
        <form:form modelAttribute="object_1" method="post">
            <tr>
                <th scope="row">${x.count}</th>
                <td>${object_1Loop.name}</td>
                <td>
                    <form:hidden path="id" value="${object_1Loop.id}"/>
                    <div class="btn-group-toggle" data-toggle="buttons">
                            <form:checkboxes element="label class='btn btn-outline-warning'"
                             cssClass="hidden" path="anotherObjectList" items="${objects_2}" itemLabel="name"/>
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-danger">Save</button>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </form:form>
    </c:forEach>
```

[How it looks right now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SzNAi.png)

[How it should look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Wjl4.png)

So the checkboxes should be checked if **object_1** has items from **objects_2** list in field **anotherObjectList**. Right now this only works for first element. What to do to make it work for every **object_1**?

Thanks in advance !